# how to ssh / su - by passing the password initially itself?

Tags: ssh

Anyone knows how to ssh / su - by passing the password initially itself?

Like:

```
ssh username@hostname  -p [password] 
pbrun su - unix_owner -p [password]
```

How can I achieve this?
It shouldn't popup for password or any RSA authentication like yes/no.

Comment: Have you considered using ssh keys instead? It's a better idea than specifying a password on the command line.

Comment: Are you trying to automate a remote process via script (ie. logon, do something, logoff) or are you trying to automate logging into an interactive shell? One is easier than the other.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will probably need a [sudoers file](http://www.go2linux.org/sudoers-how-to) to get stuff done in a `su` like manner without being prompted for a password.

I have never used ssh without a password prompt, but found [this](http://linuxproblem.org/art_9.html) which suggests it can be done...

Answer (score 1):

passing a password in clear text is not intended by ssh.
Try to learn about ssh key authentication (google would help), you won't need to type your password anymore.

ok, more detailed, try this:

on the remote machine

```
> mkdir -p ~/.ssh  #if neccessary
> touch ~/.ssh/authorized_keys2
> chmod go-rwx $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys2
```

on your local machine:

```
> ssh-keygen # if neccessary
> cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh root@remotehost "cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys2 && chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys2"
```

Answer (score 1):

A better approach would be using ssh keys, like other answers recommend, but if you really need it, you can use [expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) for that.
Just create a expect.file like this one:

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect

set username youruser
set pass yourpassword
set host yourhost

spawn ssh ${username}@${host}

expect -re "password:"
send "${pass}\r"

expect -re "$"

interact
```

and execute it:

```
expect expect.file
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't do it. You're invoking the passwd program on the remote machine. If it had a way to change a password without prompting for the old one, ANYONE could change your password if they got onto your console. You'd still need to pass the password in over the ssh link

Answer (score 0):

As for SSH, you could use RSA keys, and those won't prompt you for passwords.

As for SU, it would have to be hardcoded or you would have to create your own application to serve as a wrapper of sorts.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can pass in password directly to the ssh command (It will be stored in your history otherwise). Why don't you use keys to skip the authentication prompt.